# How can I keep a UIButton in same location after changing the Image?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that is able to change locations on the screen after it has been clicked. The user then clicks a different button to change the image of the button and I want it to stay in its new location. Currently with my code it is reverting back to the original position after changing the image. Here is the code:

First move the `Button` (newLocation is a location of a `UIImageView`):

```
movableButton.center = [newLocation center];
```

Then Change the button image by clicking a different button:

```
[movableButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"differentImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Try to turn off the autolayout. Some more of your code could help to exactly trace the error.

Comment: I know that turning off autolayout will correct the problem but I would like to use autolayout in the project.

Comment: then you might try to fix the frame of the button. For example: `movableButton.frame = CGRectMake(position.x,position.y + 10,size.width,size.height);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why it moves. I just tested it, and it does move. I need to look into why it moves and will get back to you.

But this will fix the problem of it moving.

```
CGPoint currentLoc = self.imageButton.center;
[self.imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.imageButton.center = currentLoc;
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been the only thing I have found to work. Sounds like this may be a workaround so if you find an easier way please let me know.

Comment: If you are using auto layout, you should not be modifying the `center` or `frame` directly. You should instead update your constraints to take the button’s new size into account. The reason that the button is moving is that at some point, the constraints are being re-evaluated, and the solver is ignoring the position you set manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i got your question , what you can do is start a counter in 2nd button's action:

```
-(void)secondButtonClick
{
 static int counter = 1;
   if(counter %2  == 0) 
   {
     firstButton.center =cgpoint a;  // a gain some point where you wan't to place the center
    }
 if(counter %2 != 0)
    {
      [firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
```

counter ++;

```
}
```

you can modify if condition whether you want position changed before changing  image..... Also uou can change the center alsolike this

```
a.x =a.x+10;
a.y =a.y +10;
myButton.center = a;
```

Comment: Essentially there are two buttons, one (button 1) that changes (location and image), and one that does the changing (button 2). When button 2 is pressed, it changes the first button's location. When it is pressed again, it changes the image. The problem is that when I press it the second time and it changes images, it also reverts to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction) movingButtonClicked
{
      [movingButton setFrame:CGRectMake(movingButton.frame.origin.x+10,movingButton.frame.origin.y+20,50,50)];
}

-(IBAction) changeImage
{
     [movingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"differentImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```